# Gradle fat jar _leaving out_ META-INF from child jars?

Tags: gradle

Is there any way to leave out certain paths from a Gradle fat jar.

I am using:

```
jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

from

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/Cookbook

and would like to leave out META-INF directories if possible.

Thank you!
Misha

Answer (score 15):

I haven't extensively tested it, but this should do what you're asking for:

```
jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it).matching{exclude{it.name == 'META-INF'}}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the above by TheKaptain works except instead of:
    it.name == 'META-INF'
use:
    it.path.contains('META-INF').